# suppress page break before chapter title in LyX

Tags: lyx, page-breaking, chapters

I'm using LyX and need to have the chapters to start soon after the end of the previous chapter.

A LyX solution will be most appreciated.
Document class `report` and I am not to change the document class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If the required class is `report`, why are you trying to tweak its defaults?

Comment: I've been given a cap on the number of pages so have to cut down the empty spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try going to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble, and add

```
\renewcommand\chapter{\par
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

(Normally one would need `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after, see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do), but LyX adds this automatically, so it is not necessary.)

Comment: works a treat mate.Thanks. And it worked when I have added chapters as child documents. just for you to know.